# How to query ignite RDD?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, ignite

I am using CacheConfiguration with setIndexedTypes(Long.class, StructType.class) were StructType is an object of Spark and using igniteRDD.saveValues(df.rdd()) to push values. But when i try to query on that cache getting "Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable". I am aware of annotating fields with querysqlfields on POJO but the value here is Spark object how can we do this.

Comment: How do you intend to query `StructType`? This looks incorrect to me. Can you provide the whole test as a small GitHub project. I will be able to provide feedback this way.

Comment: @Valentin I am trying to ingest parquet data inside ignite RDD. I am following this [example](https://github.com/erasmas/ignite-playground/tree/master/src/main/java/ignite). I can able to ingest the data inside ignite RDD (checked in ignite visor console).

Comment: This example doesn't do queries. I responded.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `StructType` class doesn't know anything about Ignite SQL. You should create your own key and value classes and convert each `StructType` instance to a key-value pair during loading (use `savePairs` method). After that you will be able to configure SQL as described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: my bad actually i am getting IgniteRDD from IgniteContext and its not related to the cacheConfiguration (I am using cacheConfiguration of storing RDD schema ). IgniteRDD has mainly two methods like savePairs and saveValues. Both of them require RDD object. I am getting RDD object from spark DataFrame object. How can i make this RDD (which comes from DataFrame.rdd()) SQL compliant in ignite. Please have a look at this [example](https://github.com/erasmas/ignite-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/ignite/CachedRddExample.java).

Comment: You should create your own data types which are properly configured for Ignite SQL, map the original RDD so that structs are converted to this types and then save the data in Ignite.

Comment: How can we map rdd (created from parquet) to own data types (java objects if i am not wrong). Can you provide example java code for that.

Comment: Use `RDD.map()` method. This is part of Spark API.